# Can't start mongod on terminal

Tags: mongodb

I've been trying to run a mongoimport in a bash script that I have run to store data in a localhost db.

```sh
mongoimport --host localhost --port 27017 --db cities-db --collection city --type json --file ./cities.json
```

But I can't get mongod to run since it keeps giving me this error

```sh
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-27T19:44:00.020+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-27T19:44:00.021+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-27T19:44:00.022+05:30"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-27T19:44:00.022+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-27T19:44:00.023+05:30"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-27T19:44:00.023+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-27T19:44:00.023+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-27T19:44:00.023+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-27T19:44:00.024+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":12987,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"Zenzor"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-27T19:44:00.024+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"5.0.5","gitVersion":"d65fd89df3fc039b5c55933c0f71d647a54510ae","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu2004","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-27T19:44:00.024+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Zorin","version":"16"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-27T19:44:00.024+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-27T19:44:00.025+05:30"},"s":"E",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23024,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Operation not permitted"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-27T19:44:00.025+05:30"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":40486,"file":"src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp","line":989}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-12-27T19:44:00.025+05:30"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
```

Comment: Either the user running mongod isn't allowed to create the socket in `/tmp/`. Or the socket has been created before by a different user that the current running mongodb user isn't allowed to recreate.

Comment: Looks like you try to start `mongod` more than once. Most likely `mongod` starts automatically at boot time.